# Config ARR with SSL

Tags: ssl, iis, arr

I setup 3 servers below.

ARR01 - this has public IP ([www.mytest.com](http://www.mytest.com))
Web01 - Private IP
Web02 - Private IP

Now I have a wildcard SSL, I already setup in ARR01 but should I also setup in Web01 and Web02?

Comment: It is usually your choice to make as either is OK. To utilize SSL offloading, you can follow https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing But you can also keep HTTPS on web 01 and 02 if you like. If you work for a company, the decision should be guided by your network administrators and IT security experts.

Answer (score 0):

IIS ARR can only be used as a forward proxy for HTTP, not HTTPS. SSL is terminated at the ARR server. But you can create rules to create https connections to content servers. In this case, the server certificate (wildcard certificate) needs to be imported on the ARR server and each content server.

The [blog](https://blogs.iis.net/wonyoo/ssl-off-loading-in-application-request-routing) provided by Lex Li is a good reference article. Hope it can help you.